# DateTime Format not working exactly C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to have date in specific forma `dd-mm-yyyy` `15-05-2018` and my input date format on textbox is also `dd-mm-yyyy` in backend code c# i am converting this date into DateTime for input validation purpose.

```
DateTime dDateOfBirth;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDOB.Text))
        {
            dDateOfBirth= DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text, "dd-mm-yyyy",null);

       }
```

When i check `dDateOfBirth` it stores shows me dates as `05/21/2018` while i want to pass it as `21-05-2018`

Not sure what i am doing wrong

Using 
`DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy",null);` also gives me same result `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: How do you 'check' `dDateOfBirth`? `DateTime` object itself does not have a format per se.

Comment: input format is in `dd-mm-yyy` format as i jquery Calendar for this, It is only for further validation i want to make sure that date is in `dd-mm-yyyy` format

Comment: when you pass it use **dDateOfBirth.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")**

Comment: I hope everything is working correctly as expected. As you have converted it into datetime it will keep internally based on your system's regional settings (Datetime configuration - short date format & long date format). If you want to validate it only for the date format you can do it using the string itself.

Comment: Do not worry that way VS is displaying the date while debugging.  VS using its own methods of display DataTime.  DateTime is a number and there are lots of ways of display but internally the date is always the same.

Answer (score 6):

When you check the parameter `dateOfBirth` it will display in whatever is set as your machines culture. The date can be then formatted as a string, that you can customise.

Internally dates are handled as standardised objects, you can't change that.  *Effectively you are doing nothing wrong.* It the same reason that if you were to inspect `double dbl = 0.00` you would see `dbl` is "0" not "0.00.

If you wanted to set the text in the text box you would use:

```
txtDOB.Text = dDateOfBirth.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy").
```

For more info on formatting date time to strings see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Also see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Especially

> The DateTime value type represents dates and times with values ranging
>   from 00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era)
>   through 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D. (C.E.) in the Gregorian
>   calendar.
>
> Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks, and a
>   particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January
>   1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the GregorianCalendar calendar (excluding ticks
>   that would be added by leap seconds). For example, a ticks value of
>   31241376000000000L represents the date, Friday, January 01, 0100
>   12:00:00 midnight. A DateTime value is always expressed in the context
>   of an explicit or default calendar.

So from this, you can take away that a date is just a **really** big number. When inspecting a date using breakpoints / watches etc, VisualStudio displays that as something more friendly for us mere humans.

Answer (score 0):

In the **dd-mm-yyyy** format, **mm** should be **MM**. So try with **MM**.

Comment: I had tried `dd-MM-yyyy` format first that gives me the same result `MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact("YouDateString", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score -2):

I use following code to make it work in `dd-MM-yyyy` format, There may be other ways to do it i just wanted to it simple to one line of code.

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDOB.Text))
    {
    dDateOfBirth= DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy",null);
    //dDateOfBirth is in MM/dd/yyyy format 
//so i am using next statement to convert to dd-MM-yyyy format
    string sdDateOfBirth = dFromDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }
```

Comment: As the input string is already in the expected format why we need to convert it into datetime and to string with the same format?

Comment: @Sivaprasath, In my question i have mentioned that it changes the input format `dd-MM-yyyy` to `MM/dd/yyyy` for this reason i am using second statement to convert it back to  `dd-MM-yyyy` . I am doing this to validate the input again and date is always in  `dd-MM-yyyy`  other system will search `MM/dd/yyyy` on this format. Plz read the question

Comment: Once it is a date, it is valid! In the system the date will **always** be ticks. Any other format is **for display purposes only**. If you are storing `sDateOfBirth` as a string in a database anywhere, you have just made any operations on it much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Hopefully [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GXTWOk) will help you understand there is no inherent format to a DateTime object. There is a default `ToString()` format that is based on your windows culture setting, this is used when implicitly casting to a string, as would be the case when checking in visual studio. This is formatting the sting representation of the date, for that instance only, of the DateTime object.